# Javascript how to allow array to take more than one digit?

Tags: html, arrays, loops

I've been trying lately to build up a mean calculator using html and javascript. i want to take all the inputs from the one text box add them to an array and get the average result. what i did in the following code takes only one digit because of str[i-1] is there any other alternative way of doing it? Thanks!
[Output photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDwYm.png)

```
function calculate()
{

var str= document.getElementById("meanvalue").value;
for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++)
{
    if(str[i] == ".")
    {
        sum+=parseInt(str[i-1]);
        count++;
    }
}
sum/=count;
document.getElementById("meanresult").value=sum;

}
```

Comment: Can you give an example input and expected output?

Comment: A photo has been uploaded

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to split the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example:

```js
document.getElementById('input').onkeyup = function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/gi, '');// restrict non digit
  var sum = 0;
  var array = this.value.split(/\./);
  array.forEach(function(str) {
    sum += (parseInt(str, 10) || 0); //avoid NaN
  });
  document.getElementById('output').value = (sum / array.length || 0);// avoid NaN
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<input type="text" id="output" readonly='' />
```

> i just want to know how the values are updated while im typing my
>   inputs automatically

Here, I am using `onkeyup` event to handle user input.

```js
document.getElementById('input').onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById('output').value = this.value;//get input, set output
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<input type="text" id="output" readonly='' />
```

Comment: Thank-you very much for your answer but i just want to know how the values are updated while im typing my inputs automatically ( sorry because im a beginner in javascrpt)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` function on the input. I give you a quick example here :

```js
var string = "1.3.45.7";

var array = string.split(".");
// array = [1, 3, 45, 7]

document.write(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

First split your str and than use for loop.

```
var str= document.getElementById("meanvalue").value.split('.');
```

Also remove your if condition inside the loop.

```
for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++)
{
   //if(str[i] == ".")
   // {
        sum+=parseInt(str[i-1]);`
        count++;
   // }
}
sum/=count;
document.getElementById("meanresult").value=sum;
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the code still doesnt work and no output